# OWIN-hosted web api: using windows authentication and allow anonymous access

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a `WebApi` project self-hosted using `OWIN`.

I want to enable Windows Authentication on some of the controller's actions, but allow other actions to be called anonymously.

So, following some examples I found online, I setup my WebApi like this in my `Statrup` class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication | AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous; //Allow both WinAuth and anonymous auth

    //setup routes and other stuff
    //...

    //Confirm configuration
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Then, in my controller, I created two actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public HttpResponseMessage ProtectedAction()
{
    //do stuff...
}

[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage PublicAction()
{
    //do stuff...
}
```

This, however, does not work.
Calling the action marked `AllowAnonymous` works as expected, but calling the one marked `Authorize` always returns a 401 error and the following message:

```
{
    "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

even if the caller supports windows authentication, tested on browsers (Chrome and Edge) and Postman.

What am I missing here?

Comment: how are you calling the API ?  Probably your API client you are not passing useDefaultCredentials = true.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari: as I said in the question, I tried with Postman (with NTLM authentication configured) and with browsers (Chrome and Edge) running on the same machine as the server, so they should authenticate automatically by default. Both have failed. Note that if I onyl enable `IntegratedWindowsAuthentication` in the HttpListener and then do not use the Authorize/AllowAnonymous attributes the authentication works as expected (both with Postman and with browsers). But if I do that I lose the ability to mark some actions as authorized and some as anonymous, which is waht I'm trying to do.

Comment: are you using ` appBuilder.Use(typeof(WinAuthMiddleware));` in the configure method ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari: what is the WinAuthMiddleware class and where do I find it? Is it part of a nuget package?

Comment: one more thing - are you hosting this web API  in IIS / IIS Express ?  Did you check if both windows / anonymous authentication were enabled in IIS settings.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari: as I said in the first line of my question, the api is self-hosted (I'm using the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` library to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround for this in another question.
Instead of specifying multiple auth modes (which doesn't work), you can chose the auth mode for each request at runtime, by setting up an AuthenticationSchemeSelector method like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
            listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = new 
    AuthenticationSchemeSelector(GetAuthenticationScheme);
}

private AuthenticationSchemes GetAuthenticationScheme(HttpListenerRequest httpRequest)
{
    if(/* some logic... */){
        return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;                    
    }
    else{
        return AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
    }
}
```

While not ideal (you have to manually check the request URL or some other parameter of the request to decide which method to use) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since your description about the question is bit limited I have set-up a demo app, where I implemented `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` as Provider for `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` and override `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` and `ValidateClientAuthentication`

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
        });
        app.Use<AuthenticationResponseMiddleware>();
        var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/xxxx"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1), 
            Provider = new OwinAuthorisationProvider()

        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);

    }
```

also tried to have a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and added as filters in the configuration class `.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());`

In `AuthenticationResponseMiddleware` i inherited `OwinMiddleware` and in the `public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)` method please inspect the flow of the request.

It hits `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` first in `RequestToken` method then to `OwinMiddleware` class, before going to any  `DelegatingHandler` pipelines,
mostly your authentication is implemented in this layer.

*Please comment your findings after this check, parallelly I too modify the API and update you, hope it can help you.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it looks like (correct me if I'm wrong) you're suggesting using OAuth. Instead, what I wanted to use is Windows Authentication (NTLM/Kerberos). Are the two compatible? Can I use OAuth for windows authentication? How would a browser handle this, would it present the user with a username/password prompt like it does for NTLM? Sorry for the maybe stupid questions, but I'm not familiar with OAuth.

Comment: Yes, you're right I was demonstrating with OAuth.
The example I gave was using Oauth if you want I can develop the OAuth token-based authentication.

Please refer OAuth with Windows-Authentication here, https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Kerberos+OAuth2+Grant
I have limited knowledge with windows OAuth authentication, so it may be time taking.